# Injecting JSON Data From one Function to Another in the Same Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am currently in a node, angular, express, html environment.
I have numerous buttons that I use to fill this text area with formatted text data for letters.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="flyer description">Description</label>
  <textarea style="height:400px" class="form-control" id="flyer-description"></textarea>
</div>
```

Here is my button:
`<td><button id="button1">Client Welcome</button></td>`
Here is a snippet of JS corresponding to this 1 button out of 20:

```
$(function() {
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
$('#flyer-description').load("/assets/clientwelcome.txt");
 });
  });
```

Now, while I import text, I would like to import JSON data so that when the text calls for say `{{client.name}}`, with the presence of ClientCtrl(Angular Controller) and my module it will change to the specific client's name. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in an Angular environment, you will want to adjust the patterns that you are using. In your case they are very jQuery, and not very Angular. You can fix that by adjusting the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="flyer description">Description</label>
    <textarea style="height:400px" class="form-control" id="flyer-description" ng-model="flyerdescription"></textarea>
<div>
```

```
<td><button id="button1" ng-click="loadFlyer()">Client Welcome</button></td>
```

and modifying your javascript into:

```
angular.module('<yourangularappname>').controller('ClientCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.loadFlyer = function() {
      $http.get("/assets/clientwelcome.txt").then(function(res){
          $scope.flyerdescription = res.data;
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is very good in terms of what I am speaking, however I need to inject data from my $scope.clients so I can have client info in the text. How would I inject this data (previously gotten by http.get) into the flyer function?

Comment: same controller, do I still have to use service?

Comment: If I understand correctly you will want to change the above code from $scope.flyerdescription to $scope.clients, so that $scope.clients is getting the data from your file. You will want to update the ng-model part to ng-model="clients". ng-model is the mechanism you use to bind your data between your javascript code and your HTML. Check out this fiddle, it should clarify the binding/injecting notion for you https://jsfiddle.net/jw7ejbdw/. Angular is all about 2 way data binding, which "magically" keeps your javascript and HTML in sync

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the scope clients.  `myApp.controller('ClientCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $scope.clients = [];
    $http.get('/client').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.clients = data;
        if (data == "") {
            $scope.clients = [];
        }
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Ops: could not get any data");
    });`
    I already have this, but how can put in the clients data with the flyer and still call the text?

Comment: The clientwelcome.txt is the letter, which contains things like Dear {{client.name}}, and when I fill the flyertdescription text area I would like this to come out according to the client given the id parameter. I have everything else covered, except for when clicking the button the JSON data replaces the general fields such as {{client.name}} and {{client.address}}

Comment: I suppose I am look for a functionality of next() in express

Comment: I see, so you have a template letter, with fields you want to populate based on the user? You will want to make sure your user data is available in your controller. Then after you set $scope.clients = data, you'll want to call $scope.clients.replace('{{client.name}}', <user.name>); for each of the fields you want to update. You won't have to worry about sending this data over to your HTML, angular will take care of updating it automatically

Comment: Okay, I will try and tell you of results

Comment: I am using this code here: `$scope.loadFlyer = function() {
      $http.get("/assets/clientwelcome.txt").then(function(res){
          $scope.flyerdescription = res.data;
          $scope.clients.replace('{{client.name}}', <client.name>);
      });
  };` but, this gives me an injector:modulerr error. The code without the line "`$scope.clients.replace`" works fine

Comment: Also, when I use `$scope.loadFlyer = function() { $http.get("/assets/clientwelcome.txt").then(function(res){ $scope.flyerdescription = res.data; $scope.clients.replace('{{client.name}}', $scope.clientName); }); };` I get an error saying that `$scope.clients.replace` is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$http` to fetch the data and return it asynchronously, like so:

```
    $http.get('dir/wherever/your/data/is/data.json').then(
        function (response) {
            //success
            vm.buttonData = response;
        },
        function (response) {
            //fail
            console.log("error");
        }
    );
```

You can read about `$http` here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Using `$q` to resolve `$http` is an anti pattern. `$http` already returns a promise itself. Just return `$http` and get rid of `$q`

Comment: You are completely right, I was trying to base my example off of previous work and missed the big picture. I will edit my post.